# no more text console on artful

Tags: wayland, 17.10

I have reinstalled my PC with 17.10.
Now, I can't be able to switch to the terminal console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> ...)
When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, my screen freeze and I can be able to switch again with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
I see some `agetty` process starting, so I expect to be a problem with *wayland* to switch to text mode.
What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I reported [bug 1725954](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1725954) about that.
We should wait. I have had this problem sometimes.

Text ttys are placed from 3 to 6 - use < Ctrl + Alt + F3 > to < Ctrl + Alt + F6 >.